# Using reflection to dynamically load multiple .dll files to invoke a method

Tags: c#

I am trying to invoke a method that requires multiple classes that I cannot reference in my code.

I have the following to:

1.Create a "Page" class instance by using `Page{get;set}` property.

2.Create a "Rectangle" class instance by invoking `Create(Page p)` method.

```
private void Test()
{
    try 
    {
        string assemblyPath = @"C:\Program Files\EPLAN\Platform\2022.0.3\Bin\Eplan.EplApi.DataModelu.dll";
        string assemblyClass = "Eplan.EplApi.DataModel.Graphics.Rectangle";
        string assemblyClassMethod = "Create";
        //Loading Assembly
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
        //Creating Instance of Class
        object instance = assembly.CreateInstance(assemblyClass);
        object page = assembly.CreateInstance("Eplan.EplApi.DataModel.Page");
        //Creating Method
        MethodInfo mi = RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeMethod(assembly.GetType(assemblyClass), assemblyClassMethod, new Type[] {page.GetType()});
        PropertyInfo pi = RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperty(assembly.GetType("Eplan.EplApi.DataModel.Page"), "Page");
        //Invoking Method 
        object ret2 = pi.GetValue(page);
        object obj = mi.Invoke(instance, new Object[] {ret2});
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        if (e.InnerException != null)
            MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

The code above gives me an null error saying parameter: page cannot be null.
Is there anything I have missed that people can see?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the question being asked?

Comment: Please everyone - learn to debug without the need of ever doing a `catch (Exception e) `. It's a terrible pattern that makes your code fragile.

Comment: _"classes that I cannot reference in my code."_ what does that mean?

Comment: If that means that they are private in some library, than you are either doing something wrong or something you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Comment: I am limited to the assemblies I can load during compile time. (Unable to reference them with the use keyword) Due to restrictions on the program I am using(Eplan). The code above gives me an null error saying parameter: page cannot = null.

Comment: @Enigmativity
How would you do it then?

Comment: @EugenePaul - By learning how to debug using the dev environment, by writing robust code that simply doesn't throw any errors, and by encapsulating any code that you do not have control of into a separate methods thus isolating your clean code from the vagaries of the third-party authors. There is utterly no need to present `MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException.Message)` to an end user. I would reject this code on a code review.